# How To get values of textfields from a UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

So I have this`UITableView` cell that has 4 `UITextField`, and I want to get their values on button click.

This code does not retrieve any values.

```
@IBAction func printBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "manualAddC1") as! AddFriendC1Cell

    let alias = cell.aliasTextField.text!
    let primaryPhone = cell.primaryPhoneTextField.text!
    let secondaryPhone = cell.seondaryPhoneTextField.text!
    let email = cell.emailAddressTextField.text!

    print("Alias: \(alias), Phone: \(primaryPhone), Phone2: \(secondaryPhone), Email: \(email)")
}
```

This is the screenshot of the TableView
[image]

Comment: More details would be useful.

Comment: Cn you print the output ? What's wrong ? Please, explain more

Comment: Put the screenshot of your table view

Comment: Well I got nothing, when I printed them out, even after I typed the values on the textfields.

Comment: As always, **do not** get data from the view (cell), get it from the model (data source array). And **never ever** create cells outside `cellForRow...`

Answer (score 22):

I finally figured it out with this simple solution.

```
@IBAction func saveBtnAction(_ sender: Any) {

    let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    let cell: AddFriendC1Cell = self.myTableView.cellForRow(at: index) as! AddFriendC1Cell
    self.alias = cell.aliasTextField.text!
    self.primaryPhone = cell.primaryPhoneTextField.text!
    self.secondaryPhone = cell.seondaryPhoneTextField.text!
    self.email = cell.emailAddressTextField.text!

    print("Alias: \(self.alias), Phone: \(self.primaryPhone), Phone2: \(self.secondaryPhone), Email: \(self.email)")
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that all the textfields are in the first table cell section and row (row: 0, section: 0), and I had other sections as well, but the view wouldn't show it unless I scroll down.

Comment: what if there is multiple row?

Answer (score 14):

OK. You are dequeueing a tableViewCell when you press on a button.

```
let cell = self.myTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "manualAddC1") as! AddFriendC1Cell
```

I believe that you want to get a reference to an existing tableViewCell like this:

```
   if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? AddFriendC1Cell {
        // do what you need with cell
    }
```

Even though this would work, I wouldn't suggest this approach. What if user is using a smaller-screen phone like iPhone 4 and some cells are not visible on the screen? I think that in that case `tableView.cellForRow` would return `nil` for non-visible cell.

I would suggest implementing `textField:shouldChange` in each cell with text field with a delegate to the tableView's viewController. When text is changed in the cell, delegate should propagate the change to the viewController which would save the value in an instance variable.

Then, when you press on the button, you would simply take values from instance variables.

Comment: Correct. This should be the original approach

Answer (score 1):

// 1st step

**In UITableViewCell**

```
import UIKit

@objc protocol TableViewDelegate: NSObjectProtocol{

    func afterClickingReturnInTextField(cell: ThirdTableCell)
}

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var enterTextField: UITextField!
    weak var tableViewDelegate: TableViewDelegate?


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
        enterTextField.delegate = self   
    }

    // @IBAction Of UITextfiled 
    @IBAction func tapHerre(_ sender: UITextField) {

        tableViewDelegate?.responds(to: #selector(TableViewDelegate.afterClickingReturnInTextField(cell:)))
        tableViewDelegate?.afterClickingReturnInTextField(cell: self)
    }

    // UITextField Defaults delegates
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

        enterTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        enterTextField = textField
    }  
}
```

// 2nd step

**In UITableViewCell**

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, TableViewDelegate {

    var valueToPass : String?

    func afterClickingReturnInTextField(cell: ThirdTableCell) {

        valueToPass = cell.enterTextField.text
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return youArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TableViewCell") as! TableViewCell
        cell.enterTextField.text = youArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.tableViewDelegate = (self as TableViewDelegate)
        return cell
    }
}
```

When the keyboard disappears you can find TextField value  in `valueToPass`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your tableViewCells are not dynamic.
Your cell method will looks like this.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "YourCellID") as! YourClass
    cell.yourTextField.tag = indexPath.row
//
// Alias will be tag 0
// Primary Phone will be tag 1
// Secondary Phone will be tag 2 
// Email Address will be tag 3, so on and so forth
// Then, attach to each delegate
//
    cell.yourTextField.delegate = self
}
```

Inside your UITableView handling class (which conforms to UITextFieldDelegate protocol), write this.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
let kActualText = (textField.text ?? "") + string
switch textField.tag
{
case 0:
    aliasValueHolder = kActualText;
case 1:
    primaryPhoneValueHolder = kActualText;
case 2:
    secondaryPhoneValueHolder = kActualText;
case 3:
    emailAddressValueHolder = kActualText;
default:
    print("It is nothing");
}
return true;
}
```

Then you can submit it.

Comment: There's no need for `break` in Swift `switch` because it's not fallthrough, contrary to many languages.

Comment: @EricAya , I did not came from Swift and adding `break` after case doesn't do anything bad. It's still a good programming practice. Swift still complains if u leave case or default without executable statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range:NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    //        let kActualText = (textField.text ?? "") + string

    var kActualText = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)

    kActualText = kActualText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)

    if textField.tag == 0
    {
        email_address = kActualText;
    }
    else if textField.tag == 3
    {
        password = kActualText;
    }
    else
    {
        print("It is nothing")
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should implement TextField delegates methods in the tableCell class and manage all the validations and input text in tableCell class.

Now, you will need to fetch all entered values, for this, you have to use Protocol in tableCell class and send entered value using the delegate to viewController also with the tag to identify that which value has entered like the Phone number or email.

Using this way, your code will be reduced and structured.

Happy Coding !!